# How to add email header while sending newsletter in kentico

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I am using kentico 7 and i want to add email header while sending news letter through SMTP.

This is the common feature that we used. I want to send some information with header in mail while sending newsletter. Is there any xml in kentiko or code-behind through which I can set header and send it to the subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to customize EmailQueueManager (in CMS.Newsletter namespace). There is a method

```
SendEmail(...)
```

which creates instance of EmailMessage. You can add headers to its Headers property. Unfortuantely there is no easier way to do that.

Comment: The value which we have set in the header is dynamic. In this solution how would be pass value to `SendEmail`?

Comment: what kind of value it is? could it be stored e.g. in session?

Comment: Its category that we want to send in each mail using header so we can use this in sendgrid API for fetching data on basis of category

Comment: did you guys find a solution? I am doing something very similar with unique-args and sendgrid - thanks

Comment: i developed a soln to tag emails up from EMS -> SendGrid -> Keen.IO. thanks anyway